# Flash New MovieClip Targeting Code

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, flash, html5-canvas

this time I installed the trial of Flash CC, using HTML5 Canvas rendering and scripting technology. With this form of Javascript, I am finding it very much harder than in AS3 to target a movieclip. Before you would export it for use in actionscript, but now in HTML5 I'm afraid I don't know how to do that and I'm struggling to find help for it anywhere online.
Well to better describe my problem I suppose I should show you with detail on what is going on. So here is the main script I put in the main stage timeline at frame one where the movieclip (Knight) is dragged into.

```
document.onkeydown = keyHandler.bind(this);
var self = this;

function keyHandler(event) {
    var e = window.event;

    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 39:
            this.on("knight_mc", function () {
                self.
                self.MovieClip.gotoAndPlay(7);
            }, null, true);
            console.log("HI!");
            break;
    }
}
```

This code is supposed to make my movieclip jump to frame 7 and play when pressing the right arrow key, I have found out the use of debugger and it returns "HI!" when pressing right arrow key, but I cannot seem to get it to simply target the movieclip. I hope you don't think poorly of my question as I have put alot of time and effort into writing this and would appreciate any help for this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OKAY**, I found out what I did wrong, it turns out I haven't used flash in a while and I forgot that there is an instance name for each movieclip or object on the stage that needs to be set, so I set the instance name to knight_mc and it works fine. I hope anyone reviewing this can have the help they need from my response.

Answer (score 0):

did you try

```
knight_mc.gotoAndPlay(7);
console.log("HI!");
```

?

or the direct path from root?

Comment: This isn't an answer, please post questions like these as a comment to my post like an adequate member is appropriately supposed to do by the rules of conduct.

Comment: ok, sorry, but it works. You just have to write the right path but you didn't wrote where the MC is so I can't give it for sure